# CUDA NPP GaussFilter corrupts images

Tags: qt, filter, cuda, gaussian, npp

I try to use CUDA with Qt to blur image. 
I use NPP library, nppiFilterGauss_8u_C1R works great

```
void cuda_npp_gauss_filter_qt(uchar* pSourceData, uchar* pResultData, const int &ImageLineStep, const int &ImageWidth, const int &ImageHeight)
{
       NppiSize oSizeROI;

       oSizeROI.width = ImageWidth;
       oSizeROI.height = ImageHeight;

       Npp32s SourceStep = ImageLineStep;
       Npp32s DestinationStep = ImageLineStep;

       size_t AllocationSizeInBytes = ImageLineStep * ImageHeight;
       Npp8u *pSource, *pDestination;

       cudaMalloc<Npp8u>(&pSource,AllocationSizeInBytes);
       cudaMalloc<Npp8u>(&pDestination,AllocationSizeInBytes);

       cudaMemcpy(pSource, pSourceData, AllocationSizeInBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

       nppiFilterGauss_8u_C1R(pSource, SourceStep, pDestination, DestinationStep, oSizeROI, NPP_MASK_SIZE_15_X_15);

       cudaMemcpy(pResultData, pDestination, AllocationSizeInBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}
```

but nppiFilterGaussAdvanced_8u_C1R corrupts images

```
void cuda_npp_gauss_filter_qt_advanced(uchar* pSourceData, uchar* pResultData, const int &ImageLineStep, const int &ImageWidth, const int &ImageHeight, const int &Radius)
{
      NppiSize oSizeROI;

        oSizeROI.width = ImageWidth;
        oSizeROI.height = ImageHeight;

        Npp32s SourceStep = ImageLineStep;
        Npp32s DestinationStep = ImageLineStep;

        size_t AllocationSizeInBytes = ImageLineStep * ImageHeight;
        Npp8u *pSource, *pDestination;

        cudaMalloc<Npp8u>(&pSource,AllocationSizeInBytes);
        cudaMalloc<Npp8u>(&pDestination,AllocationSizeInBytes);

        //-------------------------------------------------------

        int nFilterTaps = 2*((int)((float)ceil(Radius) + 0.5F)) + 1;

        //-------------------------------------------------------

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        //-------------- Gaussian kernel ------------------------

        double sigma = 0.3*((nFilterTaps-1)*0.5 - 1) + 0.8;

        cv::Mat GaussianKernel = cv::getGaussianKernel(nFilterTaps, sigma, CV_32F);

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        //-------------------------------------------------------

        cudaMemcpy(pSource, pSourceData, AllocationSizeInBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        nppiFilterGaussAdvanced_8u_C1R (pSource, SourceStep, pDestination, DestinationStep, oSizeROI, nFilterTaps, (Npp32f*)GaussianKernel.data);

        cudaMemcpy(pResultData, pDestination, AllocationSizeInBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    }
```

I use OpenCV to create gaussian kernel.

Xubuntu 16.04.1, Qt 5.7-1, CUDA 8.044, OpenCV 2.4.9.
Thanks.

Comment: 1. On SO, questions of the type "why isn't this code working?" are expected to include a [mcve].  What you have shown is not a complete code and not a MCVE. 2. You should always do proper error checking.  Check all npp calls for npp errors, check all cuda calls for CUDA errors, and run your code with `cuda-memcheck`, *before* asking others for help.  Even if you don't understand the error output, it will be useful to others trying to help you. 3. I believe that the gaussian kernel data is supposed to be a device pointer, not host pointer. You are supposed to transfer that data to device memory

Comment: You'll also need to offset your work into the center of the image.  You can't have an ROI size that is equal to the source and destination image sizes, because when the gaussian kernel is applied, it needs a radius of elements on each side.  Running your code with `cuda-memcheck` will certainly point out problems.  You'll need to make adjust ments along the lines I've indicated until `cuda-memcheck` reports no errors.  Then at least you'll know you are not asking NPP to access data out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 5):

NPP functions require memory to be allocated on device. OpenCV Mat (`GaussianKernel` in this case) is allocated on host by default.

So the following line of code becomes invalid.

```
nppiFilterGaussAdvanced_8u_C1R (pSource, SourceStep, pDestination, DestinationStep, oSizeROI, nFilterTaps, (Npp32f*)GaussianKernel.data);
```

The parameter `(Npp32f*)GaussianKernel.data` should be copied to device before passing on to NPP function. It may be achieved like this:

```
float* GaussianKernel_d;
size_t GaussianKernelBytes = GaussianKernel.step() * GaussianKernel.rows;

cudaMalloc<float>(&GaussianKernel_d, GaussianKernelBytes);
cudaMemcpy(GaussianKernel_d, GaussianKernel.data, GaussianKernelBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

nppiFilterGaussAdvanced_8u_C1R (pSource, SourceStep, pDestination, DestinationStep, oSizeROI, nFilterTaps, GaussianKernel_d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. It works now.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------
//-------------- Gaussian kernel ------------------------

   double sigma = 0.3*((nFilterTaps-1)*0.5 - 1) + 0.8;

   cv::Mat GaussianKernel = cv::getGaussianKernel(nFilterTaps, sigma, CV_32F);

   Npp32f* pGaussianKernel;

   size_t GaussianKernelBytes = GaussianKernel.step * GaussianKernel.rows;

   cudaMalloc<Npp32f>(&pGaussianKernel, GaussianKernelBytes);

   cudaMemcpy(pGaussianKernel, GaussianKernel.data, GaussianKernelBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

 //-------------------------------------------------------
 //-------------------------------------------------------

 cudaMemcpy(pSource, pSourceData, AllocationSizeInBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

 nppiFilterGaussAdvanced_8u_C1R (pSource, SourceStep, pDestination, DestinationStep, oSizeROI, nFilterTaps, pGaussianKernel);

 cudaMemcpy(pResultData, pDestination, AllocationSizeInBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Comment: Glad to know that :). You may consider accepting the answer.